# Last item in scroll view is being cut off

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The text in the bottom is being half-cut. I tried to search for the reason and tried to solve it but no luck I have a card view inside which there is a relative layout and inside that a scroll view and inside the scroll view a linear layout. Any hint or help in the cole will be helpful

Layout XML code:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:id="@+id/cardView"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Dua’s after Salah"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#d6d6d6"

    />
    <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:id="@+id/subTitle"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="To be recited after every farz salah"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:background="#d6d6d6"

    />

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/subTitle">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                      android:layout_marginRight="8dp">


            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/duaTV"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:text="بِسْمِ اللهِ ، تَوَكَّلْتُ عَلَى اللهِ وَلَا حَوْلَ وَلَا قُوَّةَ إِلَّا بِاللهِ"
            />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/pronounciationHeading"
                      android:text="Pronounciation"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/heading_margin_top"
                      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                      android:id="@+id/pronounciationTV"
                      android:text="Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text"
                      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/translationHeading"
                      android:text="Translation"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/heading_margin_top"
                      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/translationTV"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                      android:text="Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text"
                      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/benefitHeading"
                      android:text="Benefit"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/heading_margin_top"
                      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/benefitTV"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                      android:text="Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text
                    Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text
                    Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text
                    Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text
                    Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciation Text Pronounciation TextPronounciati"
                      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            />

            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/reference"
                      android:text="Reference"
                      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                      android:textAlignment="center"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My output:

[image: My output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
```

the layout_marginTop is pushing the layout down out of bounds. Line 40.